# jekyll listing markdown notices

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

Structure of my project:

```
/_config.yml
./_layouts
./_posts
./_posts/2011-07-29-my-first-jekyll-post.markdown
./_notices/2011-07-29-my-first-notice.markdown
./_notices/2011-07-30-my-second-notice.markdown
./_site
./index.html
```

With post it works:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
 ... listing all posts ...
{% endfor %}
```

With news not working:

```
{% for notice in site.notices %}
 ... listing all notices ...
{% endfor %}
```

Notices does not work. How can I achieve a listing of items similar to the post listing?

Answer (score 2):

By default, only the `_posts` folder holds iterable items. If you use a recent version of Jekyll, you can use the new [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) feature. In your example, add the following to your `_config.yml`

```
collections:
  - noticies
```

Please note, though, that this feature is in its early development and might change until the it stabilizes. Also, just for the record, the English plural of notice is notices.

Comment: Perhaps Tiago Casanova speaks [Catalan](https://translate.google.com/?ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#auto/en/noticies)?

Comment: Possible. The rest of the path is English, though. And I actually spent hours of debugging time with mistakes like that, so a small hint could be useful. :)

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if that solved your problem. :)